# Images loading in Eclipse but not working in Runable Jar

Tags: java, jar

I'm not sure what other code you will need but the only images working are Sprites/projectile.png

and some of the ones that won't are 
Sprites/Characters/spikeEnemy.png
Sprites/Characters/circleEnemy.png

If you need anymore of the code, I will provide.

Edit: Provided Code

```
    Image sprite = new ImageIcon("Sprites/Characters/spikeEnemy.png").getImage();

    sprite = (e) ? new ImageIcon("Sprites/enemyProjectile.png").getImage() : new ImageIcon("Sprites/projectile.png").getImage();
```

(e: true for enemy, false for ally)
sprite is declared earlier as (private Image sprite)

Comment: Dear Antonio, with this description it will be difficult to help, please provide minimal code that you think is related to the problem.

Comment: I presume you're using `File` instead of `getResourceAsStream()`?

Comment: I added some of the code